# Sending dropped pin via message

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm planning an Android app which includes an instant messaging feature, backed by a Firebase Realtime database.

I would like to include enable users to:

1. Open Google maps and drop a pin somewhere
2. Send the pinned map to the other user
3. With a preview of the map and the pin in the message content

Note: this is different to sending current location

I think I can manage the first step, could someone help me with step 2 and 3? 
Do I need to use the Google Maps API?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Open Google maps and drop a pin somewhere

You can use [Google Map API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/intro) and [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map-with-marker) how you can add a marker on the map.

> 2) Send the pinned map to the other user

Every time you add a marker to the map, save the latitude and longitude in Firebase database under user object. To send the pin to a user, just get those coordinates and add them to the other user location.

> 3) With a preview of the map and the pin in the message content Note/this is different to sending current location

If I understand correctly, this ia how you can get [current location](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/current-place-tutorial). You also should use [Lite Mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/lite) which provides you a bitmap image of a map at a specified location and zoom level.

> Do I need to use the Google Maps API?

Definitely, yes!

Comment: thanks for your help!
Just one more question (I wasn't clear before I think):
"3) With a preview of the map and the pin in the message content"

Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome! Please see my updated answer.